# Batch apex class to create multiple child records

Tags: apex

I have created batch apex class to create multiple customers if account has no customers. Below is the code which creates one customer after running batch apex.

But my requirement is to create 7 customers from Date given in Account record. 
Example: 
If Date__c in Account is 25-10-2017, then 7 customers. 1st customer should be created with Date__c = 25-10-2017, 2nd customer should be created with Date__c = 26-10-2017 till 7 days.

Below batch class creates a single customer for Account which has no customer:

```
global class batchContactCreate implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {
global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
   return Database.getQueryLocator([
            select Name, Date__c from Account where ID NOT IN (SELECT Account__c from S1_Customer__c)]);  
}


global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Account> scope) {
     List<S1_Customer__c> cList = new List<S1_Customer__c>();
     for(Account a : scope)
     {
        S1_Customer__c cust = new S1_Customer__c(Name =a.Name, Account__c = a.Id, Phone__c = '1212121232', Date__c = a.Date__c);
        cList.add(cust); 

     }
     insert cList;
}   

global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your looking for something like this -

```
List<S1_Customer__c> cList = new List<S1_Customer__c>();
for(Account a : scope){
    for(Integer i=0;i<7;i++){
        S1_Customer__c cust = new S1_Customer__c(Name =a.Name, Account__c = a.Id, Phone__c = '1212121232', Date__c = a.Date__c.addDays(i));
        cList.add(cust);
    }
}
insert cList;
```

For each account you want to run a loop, while incrementing the date by 1 day.

Comment: Thanks Jitender. That's working.  Can you please let me know how to create child record Invoice__c with field values Name, Customer__c for each S1_Customer__c. Suppose, if there are 7 customers, for every customer, it should have child record Invoice.

Comment: @SFDC You can add the code to create a child record Invoice__c inside the second `for` loop and assign them the parent Id for `cust`. You will also need a new list to add these Invoices and insert them after both the loops, just like you have done for customers.

Comment: Thanks. I have wrote as. it's working fine. plz tell me is it correct approach ?
      List<Task__c> invList = new List<Task__c>();
    for(Account a : scope){
    for(Integer i=0;i<7;i++){
        S1_Customer__c cust = new S1_Customer__c(Name =a.Name, Account__c = a.Id, Phone__c = '1212121232', Date__c = a.Date__c.addDays(i));
        cList.add(cust);
    }
    }
    insert cList;
    for(S1_Customer__c c:cList){
    Task__c i = new Task__c();
    i.Name= c.Name;
    i.Customer__c = c.Id;
    invList.add(i);
    }
    insert invList;
    }

Comment: @SFDC It is really hard to read that code, do you mind asking this in a separate question? And make sure to add proper formatting

Comment: Hi Jitendar. thanks. Here is url: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/196967/batch-apex-class-to-create-multiple-child-records-and-schedulable-class-for-batc