# Batch apex class to create multiple child records and schedulable class for batch

Tags: apex

I wrote below code to create 7 customers from Date given in Account record and for every customer i am adding task. Below code working fine. please let me know if batch class and schedulable follows the proper coding standards.

Example: 
 If Date__c in Account is 25-10-2017, then 7 customers. 1st customer should be created with Date__c = 25-10-2017, 2nd customer should be created with Date__c = 26-10-2017 till 7 days.

```
global class batchContactCreate implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {

    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator([ select Name, Date__c from Account where ID NOT IN (SELECT Account__c from S1_Customer__c)]);  
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Account> scope) {
        List<S1_Customer__c> cList = new List<S1_Customer__c>();
        List<Task__c> invList = new List<Task__c>();
        for(Account a : scope){
            for(Integer i=0;i<7;i++){
                S1_Customer__c cust = new S1_Customer__c(Name =a.Name, Account__c = a.Id, Phone__c = '1212121232', Date__c = a.Date__c.addDays(i));
                cList.add(cust);
            }
        }
        insert cList;
        for(S1_Customer__c c:cList){
            Task__c i = new Task__c();
            i.Name= c.Name;
            i.Customer__c = c.Id;
            invList.add(i);
        }
        insert invList;
    }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {

    }
}
```

Schedulable class for above batch:

```
global class SampleBatchScheduler implements Schedulable {

    // Execute at regular intervals
    global void execute(SchedulableContext ctx){
        batchContactCreate batch = new batchContactCreate();
        Database.executebatch(batch, 200);
    }
}
```

Comment: When the relation between batch and schedule is 1:1 I personally like to put them both inside the same class, so  
`global class batchContactCreate implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Schedulable {`  

and copy-paste the execute from the schedulable into the batch itself. It helps keeping things together and reduces the fishing around. But only if you are not following any naming convention for Batches and Schedules.

Comment: Looks all good and Sergio's suggestion is a good one, you can put it in the same class.